# How to build a desktop apps using flex?

Tags: apache-flex, air

can anyone help me in building a desktop app that can compile java, c, c++ files and display the results using the flex app

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Adobe AIR](http://www.adobe.com/products/air/) lets you create desktop applications based on Flex framework. As of AIR 2.0, you can run [native processes from AIR](http://mchristoff.com/2009/12/using-the-air-2-0-nativeprocess-api-to-control-mplayer/). Thus you can call the corresponding compilers of java/c/c++ from your app and display the results using your pretty flex controls.

Answer (score 0):

The above poster is correct in offering a viable solution that already exists within the flash platform. Depending on your requirements you may just be looking to reduce your code library or save some time you could look into utilizing a cross compilable language like Haxe. In this case you would write code in the Haxe language (similar to ECMAScript) that can then be cross compiled to C++/neko/flash ASVM2/PHP, etc..

Answer (score 0):

Air 3.0 can run Adobe Native Extensions (ANE), not Air 2.0 as stated above. Flash Builder 4.6 which is now in Beta (to be released before end this year) will let you build Flex apps with ANE in an IDE environment. Currently you need to use the command line.